# Increase resistance to turn on a light bulb

Tags: switches, resistance, potentiometer

I’m wondering if it is possible to use a potentiometer to turn on/off a lightbulb in a binary manner.

I’m thinking high resistance = light on. Low resistance = light off. Is there such a circuit? Does it have a name?

Comment: Transistors used as DC switches also have defined thresholds for voltage or current to act as logic level or binary level power switches.  AC full bridge would be needed for a DC switch with suitable rating

Comment: You will want to make sure you have some hysteresis. So look for the term when considering such a circuit.

Answer (score 2):

A common approach for turning analog into digital in a simple manner such as this is to use a **[comparator circuit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparator)**.

Basically, you have a reference voltage that is your switch point.  You have the potentiometer change a voltage into the other input of the comparator.  Once it crosses the reference voltage, the output switches state.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f6Ivt0.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Answer (score 2):

The circuit you are looking for is called a comparator.

A comparator is just an op-amp in open-loop configuration, which will amplify the difference between the input and reference voltages such that any difference between them results in an output that is one of the power rails of the op-amp -- i.e., a digital signal. In a non-inverting configuration, the output voltage will be +VDD for Vi > Vref, and the output voltage will be 0 for Vi < Vref. You can set Vref with a simple voltage divider.

You can make the light turn on at low resistance by putting it on the low leg of a resistor divider.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fNpba1.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

To avoid flickering around the threshold point you will want to add some hysteresis which separates one threshold into separate upward and downward thresholds.

Note that this only provides an "enable" signal and isn't suitable for driving AC loads. As with all mains power level voltages, danger lies ahead.